# SSRS Tablix Repeating Headers Not Working

Tags: reporting-services

This question has been asked many times but I have done everything to get Repeating Row Headers for more than one group. What I have done already was the following:

1. In the Row Groups, I clicked on the down arrow next to Column Groups and switched to Advanced Mode
2. In the static row for the first Group (TechnicianLogName), I set the following properties: KeepWithGroup = After and RepeatOnNewPage = True and FixedData = True and it is working as expected.
   [image]
3. In the first static row for the second group(Task Date), I did the same steps as in step 2, set the field values to KeepWithGroup = After and RepeatOnNewPage = True but the Date row is not repeating on the necessary continuous pages.
   [image]

What else am I missing?

Comment: Not sure why it's not working but rather than waste more time with it, I would create a table for the Technician and Task date fields with one wide column and then remove the Tech and Task groups from the current table, and put it in the tech table.